# How to change selected color of edittext border in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am new to Android and working on a login page.
I have two `EditText` items and want to change the bottom border color of the `EditText`, when it is selected.
I dont want an `EditText` with all borders, only the bottom border.
I have tried as below but it is not working:

**EditText**

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/et_email"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:hint="Enter Your Email"

            />
```

Comment: Use a StateList drawable, a.k.a. "Selector".

Answer (score 0):

Create a drawable xml file button_focused.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> <!--background color of box-->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:top="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:left="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#000000" />  <!-- color of stroke -->
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

You should create xml for pressed and normal as well.

Finally you should use the below code to change the color or background based on focussed normal and pressed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```